# Is shaka available as a js package?

Tags: shaka

I need a shaka packager in only one module, instead of npm install and increasing app bundle size. I need to do this. Is it available as a js package?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are looking for just the shaka player, you can use:

https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/shaka-player/2.5.6/shaka-player.compiled.js